# Generic interface parameters in a generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I have the following generic interface:

```
public interface IContainer<T>
```

and a generic interface that acts as a container for these generic interfaces:

```
public interface IGroupOfContainers<TContainer, TValue>
    where TContainer : IContainer<TValue>
```

Now I can define some classes:

```
public class SomeContainer<T> : IContainer<T>
...

public class OtherContainer<T> : IContainer<T>
...

public class SomeGroupOfContainers<TContainer, TValue>
    : IGroupOfContainers<TContainer, TValue>
    where TContainer : IContainer<TValue>
...

public class OtherGroupOfContainers<TContainer, TValue>
    : IGroupOfContainers<TContainer, TValue>
    where TContainer : IContainer<TValue>
...
```

Now I want `IntGroupManager` to be able to work with any object that complies with the `IGroupOfContainers<IContainer<int>, int>` interface:

```
public class IntGroupManager
{
    public IGroupOfContainers<IContainer<int>, int> IntGroup { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

But when I try:

```
var manager= new IntGroupManager();
manager.IntGroup = new GroupOfContainers<Container<int>, int>
    as IGroupOfContainers<IContainer<int>, int>;
```

I get a *"Suspicious cast: there is no type which is inherited from both `GroupOfContainers<Container<int>, int>` and `IGroupOfContainers<IContainer<int>, int>`"* warning, and when I attempt to run the code, `manager.IntGroup` is set to `null`, as the cast failed.

If I change the type signature of the `IntGroup` property to

```
public IGroupOfContainers<Container<int>, int> IntGroup { get; set; }
```

(changing `IContainer` to the concrete class `Container`), the code executes properly. However, I then wouldn't be able to instantiate an instance of `IntGroupManager` with an `IntGroup` of type, say, `GroupOfContainers<OtherContainer<int>, int>`, since `OtherContainer` is not derived from `Container`.

I could introduce generic parameters into the definition of `IntGroupManager`, perhaps rewriting it as

```
public class IntGroupManager<TContainer> where TContainer : IContainer<int>
```

However, this would bind any instance of `IntGroupManager` to a specific type of `IContainer`; I wouldn't be able to do

```
var manager = new IntGroupManager<Container<int>>();

// Set manager.IntGroup and do some things with it
// This is okay
manager.IntGroup = new GroupOfContainers<Container<int>, int>();
// manager executes some code involving IntGroup and manipulates its internal state

// Set manager.IntGroup to something else and do things with it
// This is not okay, since OtherContainer<int> is not derived from Container<int>
manager.IntGroup = new GroupOfContainers<OtherContainer<int>, int>();
```

and so I lose some flexibility.

How can I properly define the `IntGroup` property to be of any type conforming to `IGroupOfContainers<IContainer<int>, int>`? I want to be able to use the same instance of `IntGroupManager` with any `IntGroup` object that conforms to `IGroupOfContainers<IContainer<int>, int>`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is hard to say without seeing how you used `TContainer` and `TValue` (input or output?) but, have you tried using `out` keyword for the generic type arguments? For details you can check [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

```
public interface IContainer<out T>

public interface IGroupOfContainers<out TContainer, TValue>
    where TContainer : IContainer<TValue>
```

Comment: If it were either input or output, and not both, this would be the solution, right? Is there any way to do this even if IGroupOfContainers defined functions that used TContainer as both input and output?

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to your question in the comments of Mehmet's answer (sorry, too long for a comment):

> If it were either input or output, and not both, [covariance] would be the solution, right? Is there any way to do this even if IGroupOfContainers defined functions that used TContainer as both input and output?

Let's continue with your example and assume that the following statement works:

```
var g = new GroupOfContainers<Container<int>, int>
    as IGroupOfContainers<IContainer<int>, int>;
```

Let's assume that `IGroupOfContainers<TContainer, TValue>` has a method `AddContainer(TContainer)`:

```
g.AddContainer(new OtherContainer<int>());
```

This would compile, since `OtherContainer<int>` is an `IContainer<int>`.

However, you just added an `OtherContainer` to a group of `Container`s! That's why you cannot do what you want to do unless you prevent `IGroupOfContainers` from taking `TContainer` inputs.

Comment: This makes it very clear why C# behaves like this. Thanks for the clarification!